# Is it possible to make CFBundleTypeIconFile dynamic?

Tags: cocoa, quicklook

Is it possible to make the icon of a specific file-type have an icon based on its contents.

Like for example images on OS X, which shows their thumbnails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see Apple's "[Quick Look Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Quicklook_Programming_Guide/)"

Comment: But is that a just a quicklook plugin, or does it also change the icon in Finder?

Comment: the QuickLook preview will be used in some cases. Try browsing your text files "as Icons" in Finder.

Comment: A QuickLook plug-in can generate two different things: “previews” and ”thumbnails”. Thumbnails are used as icons.